# What are the executable names of MySQL client and Admin Application (GUI)?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I've tried searching for for my MySQL client and manager using Dash Home, and cannot find them. I've tried using `find` on the command line, but don't know what the application names are respectively.

These two applications were migrated from 10.04, and both Ubuntu Software and Synaptic say they're installed.

How do I find them, so I can either put them into the status bar or create desktop icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call mysql client with `mysql` (and some arguments) - there is no "natvie" gui. You can install something like MySQL Workbench witch can work as both a client and an admin.

As far as the admin, if you actually installed the server, it comes with `phpmyadmin`. You just have to create a virtual host and connect to it with a browser.

Comment: It isn't that I'm trying to install GUI. The two GUI programs were installed and migrated up from 10.04 The GUI had a round blue icon and the query analyzer had a lightening bolt icon. The GUI was installed. It isn't that I'm going to install it. I need to know what each GUI program's file name is. I know about mysql. That is the command line administrative command line interface that also allows queries.

Comment: What GUI did you install?

Comment: mysql-client 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 and mysql-server 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, but I note navigator is not installed. Have the two guis been eliminated?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no graphical interface built in (other than `phpMyAdmin`)... you need to install something 3rd party (MySQL Workbench is a pretty good choice)...